# facebook graph comments filter and summary

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve only top-level comments with a count or all comments (including replies) for a given post from the Facebook graph.

Has anyone got the Facebook graph comment filter or summary fields on comment graph calls to work? It says in the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graphapi/guides/comments/ you can add a ?filter=stream and or ?summary=true to the graph url to include comment replies and or summary information (counts) in the collection of returned comments.

A hypothetical example is: for a public feed Facebook will tell you that a post has 100 comments and this number includes replies, when you actually retrieve the comments you may only get back 80 because the graph only returns top-level comments not comments and their replies.

Real example

```
graph.facebook.com/10151579052696276/comments/
```

gets all the first 25 comments from a post (using the object_id) but excludes replies. It only returns top level comments. This is a problem because the post comment count Facebook returns doesn't match the number of comments it returns. If you try and make comment pagination your screwed because its inconsistent.

To fix this i tried to add the filter stream and summary

```
graph.facebook.com/10151579052696276/comments/?filter=stream&summary=true
```

returns the exact same JSON.

I've tried including user access tokens (with all permissions) and an app token

try it yourself in the graph explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your request Url is wrong
Delete "/" after "comments"

url should be like this;
graph.facebook.com/10151579052696276/comments?filter=stream&summary=true

Answer (score 2):

Here's your answer:

**>> For Comment Counts with their replies:**
https://graph.facebook.com/80329313253_10153617216088254/comments?filter=stream&summary=true&access_token=yourtoken

**>> For Comment Counts without their replies:**
https://graph.facebook.com/80329313253_10153617216088254/comments?filter=toplevel&summary=true&access_token=yourtoken

**Note**: The above urls return a json object having two members (**data array**: which will show you the comment data, **summary object**: this will include a field showing total_counts)

It took long time for me to figure out that the summary is shown after all the comments array.  Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question entirely, but are you looking for a total number of Facebook comments for a given post?  If so, this works:

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/comments?summary=true&access_token=XXX

After all the comment id's, comment likes, etc there should be this summary:

summary: {
order: "chronological",
total_count: NUMBER
}

Answer (score 1):

It returns the same json, because you request for a LIST of comments.
If you just want the summary, you have to avoid any pagination with the limit-parameter. try this:
graph.facebook.com/10151579052696276/comments/?filter=stream&summary=true&**limit=0**

in php i used this syntax:
$url="http://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{comments.limit(0).summary(total_count)&10151579052696276";
$FB_Request = file_get_contents($url);

Comment: Thanks, your form was the only one that worked.